# Do I need to free char in this scenario

Tags: c++, memory-management

My code looks something like this:

```
const char *msg = getMessageFromAnObject(); // gets one slot from a char **

return std::string ( msg );
```

Now, do I need to free up msg or is it implicitly taken care.

Thanks.
Pavan.

Comment: It depends on what `getMessageFromAnObject` does, and how your other implementation works.

Comment: That API is picking up an entry from a char** that has been allocated by it explicitly.

Comment: What does the documentation for `getMessageFromAnObject` say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that `getMessageFromAnObject()` returns a `const char*` suggests that you do not need to free the return value. But this is just a convention that tends to be used in C APIs -- the only way to be sure is to look at the documentation, or the source if you have it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on implementation of your object. Who is owner of returned data?
If your object will free memory in it's destructor, it might be not necessary to free memory on your side. But if that object allocated new memory in that function (so you are owner of the returned data), you have to delete it.